# Bison, interfacing with flex in c++

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I try to write a compiler, and use flex/bison for the scanning and parsing.
My question is about how these 2 can communicate, so that lex passes a token type, and (if needed) a semantic value.

The problem is that I find different (conflicting?) documentations.

For example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Split-Symbols.html#Split-Symbols) they mention to use yylval subfields for the semantic value, and to return the token type (probably and integer).

```
[0-9]+ {
   yylval->build<int> () = text_to_int (yytext);
   return yy::parser::token::INTEGER;
}
[a-z]+ {
   yylval->build<std::string> () = yytext;
   return yy::parser::token::IDENTIFIER;
 }
```

But then, I see (also in the official docs) [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Calc_002b_002b-Scanner.html#Calc_002b_002b-Scanner):

```
"-"      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_MINUS  (loc);
"+"      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_PLUS   (loc);
"*"      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_STAR   (loc);
"/"      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_SLASH  (loc);
"("      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_LPAREN (loc);
")"      return yy::calcxx_parser::make_RPAREN (loc);
":="     return yy::calcxx_parser::make_ASSIGN (loc);

{int}      {
  errno = 0;
  long n = strtol (yytext, NULL, 10);
  if (! (INT_MIN <= n && n <= INT_MAX && errno != ERANGE))
    driver.error (loc, "integer is out of range");
  return yy::calcxx_parser::make_NUMBER (n, loc);
}
{id}       return yy::calcxx_parser::make_IDENTIFIER (yytext, loc);
.          driver.error (loc, "invalid character");
<<EOF>>    return yy::calcxx_parser::make_END (loc);
```

Here, yylval is not mentioned at all, and what we return is some strange make_??? functions, that I fail to understand where they are defined, what parameters they accept and what they return.

Can somebody clarify to me the is the difference between those 2 approaches, and, if I should use the second, a short explanation on those mysterious make_??? methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation section you link to is the first of two sections which describe *alternative* APIs. It would be better to start reading at the [beginning](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Scanner-Interface.html), where it is explained that:

> The actual interface with yylex depends whether you use unions, or variants.

The example you cite uses variants, and therefore uses the [complete symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Complete-Symbols.html) interface, where the `make_*` methods are defined. (These are not standard library or Boost variants; they are a simple discriminated union class defined by the bison framework.)

Which of the APIs you use is entirely up to you; they both have advantages and disadvantages.

There is also a third alternative: build both the parser and the lexer using C interfaces. That doesn't stop you from using C++ datatypes, but you cannot put them directly into the parser stack; you need to use pointers and that makes memory management more manual. (Actually, there are two different C APIs as well: the traditional one, in which the parser automatically calls the scanner when it needs a token, and the "push" interface, where the scanner calls the parser with each token.)

Comment: I think I understand now.. Thanks a lot for the answer!